# Query array of dictionary in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection  db.orders in mongodb, this is a example:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed269e0f18b5c0d33150ce1"),
        "user" : ObjectId("5ed16ace5b16a6100c1ae744"),
        "cart" : {
                "items" : [
                        {
                                "item" : {
                                        "_id" : "5ed16847fb395528f07f2d19",
                                        "tipo" : "anillo",
                                        "imagePath" : "../images/anillos/anillo1.png",
                                        "title" : "Anillo Geo",
                                        "description" : "Anillo en bronce con baño en oro de 24k",
                                        "price" : 25,
                                        "qty" : 1
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "item" : {
                                        "_id" : "5ed16847fb395528f07f2d2e",
                                        "tipo" : "collar",
                                        "imagePath" : "../images/collares/collar10.png",
                                        "title" : "Cadenita Pendulo cuarzos naturales",
                                        "description" : "Cadenita en bronce con baño en oro de 18k.",
                                        "price" : 20,
                                        "qty" : 1
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "item" : {
                                        "_id" : "5ed16847fb395528f07f2d26",
                                        "tipo" : "anillo",
                                        "imagePath" : "../images/anillos/anillo14.png",
                                        "title" : "Anillo mandala de cristales",
                                        "description" : "Anillo en bronce con baño en oro de 24k, incluye estuche de madera ",
                                        "price" : 20,
                                        "qty" : 1
                                }
                        }
                ],
                "totalQty" : 3,
                "totalPrice" : 65
        },
        "address" : "carrera 9/ Madrid",
        "city" :  "Madrid",
        "name" : "Marcela R",
        "paymentId" : "ch_1GoIGGByvh8EqLzfNGV02e3e",
        "oderdate" : ISODate("2020-05-30T14:12:48.624Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I need to know how many title: "Anillo geo" and generally how many cart.items.item.title have been sold. I try different methods but I end up with something like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed27fee825300b7d182355d"),
        "cart" : {
                "items" : [
                        {
                                "title" : "Anillo Geo",
                                "price" : 25,
                                "qty" : 1,
                                "tipo" : "anillo"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Cadenita Pendulo cuarzos naturales",
                                "price" : 29,
                                "qty" : 1,
                                "tipo" : "collar"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Anillo mandala de cristales",
                                "price" : 29,
                                "qty" : 1, 
                                "tipo" : "anillo"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

But I need a query that give me something like:

```
{"_id" : Anillo Geo, count: 5} 
{"_id" : Cadenita Pendulo cuarzos naturales, count: 8}...
```

Anyone have any idea of how to do this query?
Kind regards!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to unwind `cart.items` array & group on `_id + title` to count no.of titles got repeated for an `_id` document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$cart.items"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { _id: "$_id", title: "$cart.items.item.title" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  /** transform fields the way you want in output */
  {
    $project: { _id: "$_id._id", title: "$_id.title", count: 1 }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5qwUs76cMGc)

**Note :**

If possible try to use `$match` as first stage to do this operation on a single doc i.e; for a single user or at-least lesser docs rather than on an entire collection.